# Rails 5 before_destroy throw(:abort)

Tags: rspec, callback, ruby-on-rails-5, has-and-belongs-to-many

I'm working in a legacy Rails app that has been diligently upgraded with each major version of Rails and we're currently on rails 5.1 and I can't get a `before_destroy` to prevent the deletion if it fails a validation

I've been reading that `return false` has been deprecated and we're all supposed to use `throw :abort` but neither are working. I'm not getting any errors, the join record just gets deleted despite the `throw`

user.rb:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :permission_users
  has_many :permissions, through: :permission_users, dependent: :destroy
end
```

join model permission_user.rb:

```
class PermissionUser < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :permission

  before_destroy :check_before_removing!

  private

  def check_before_removing!
    if not_valid? # condition isn't important
      errors.add :base, exception.message
      throw(:abort)
    end
  end
end
```

my spec:

```
specify "cannot have their admin permissions revoked" do
  expect {
    admin.permissions.delete admin_permission
  }.to change { admin.permissions.count }.by(0)       
end

# => expected `admin.permissions.count` to have changed by 0, but was changed by -1
```

Comment: Bit off-topic, but: `expect{}.to change{}.by(0)` -> `expect{}.not_to change{}`

Comment: I actually trimmed down the spec to focus on the problem. I'm actually testing that 2 different values don't change and apparently rspec doesn't like the `.to_not change { ... }.and change { ... }` but thank you

Answer (score 7):

There's [a catch with this callback](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#destroying-an-object):

> before_destroy callbacks should be placed before dependent: :destroy
>   associations (or use the prepend: true option), to ensure they execute
>   before the records are deleted by dependent: :destroy.

So please try

```
before_destroy :check_before_removing!, prepend: true
```

Comment: unless I'm doing something wrong, this still isn't working. Same failure, still getting to the `throw(:abort)` and a logging after the `throw` doesn't get printed out so I know it's throwing or whatever at that point

Answer (score 5):

try to do something like this

`before_destroy :check_before_removing, prepend: true`

`def check_before_removing 
  if true && some_condition
     throw(:abort)
  end
 end`